# How can I decode tbsCertificate content?

Tags: certificate, x509, asn.1

I was trying to see what's the content of a tbsCerticate.

This is what I have done:

1. Download a certificate from website ([baidu.com](https://www.baidu.com)) in der binary format.
2. Use `openssl x509 -in bd.cer -inform cer -text -noout >> bd.cer.noout.txt` to translate into text. Now I can see what's in the certificate[image]
3. `openssl asn1parse -inform der -in bd.cer > bd.cer.asn1` parse the certificate. According to [rfc5280](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt), second line is tbsCertificate content, which is `4:d=1  hl=4 l=2326 cons: SEQUENCE`.
4. `dd if=bd.cer of=bd.cer.tbsCertificate skip=4 bs=1 count=2330` to dump the bytes.
5. `openssl x509 -in bd.cer.tbsCertificate -inform der -text -noout >> bd.cer.tbs.txt` Now I want to parse it bd.cer.tbsCertificate to x509 format to see it, but it failed.

```
unable to load certificate
140421447947392:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
140421447947392:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=X509_CINF
140421447947392:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:646:Field=cert_info, Type=X509
```

I want to know why I can't translate the `bd.cer.tbsCertificate` into x509 just like `bd.cer`. Do I miss something? From the error, it seems that the structure is not right.

What should I do if I want to see tbsCertificate in txt to know what exactly are encrypted. Thank you for your help!

Comment: please dont post pictures of text...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From the error, it seems that the structure is not right.

Correct.  The x509 command can only read a Certificate.

```
Certificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
    tbsCertificate       TBSCertificate,
    signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
    signatureValue       BIT STRING  }

TBSCertificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
    version         [0]  EXPLICIT Version DEFAULT v1,
    serialNumber         CertificateSerialNumber,
    signature            AlgorithmIdentifier,
    issuer               Name,
    validity             Validity,
    subject              Name,
    subjectPublicKeyInfo SubjectPublicKeyInfo,
    issuerUniqueID  [1]  IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
                         -- If present, version MUST be v2 or v3
    subjectUniqueID [2]  IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
                         -- If present, version MUST be v2 or v3
    extensions      [3]  EXPLICIT Extensions OPTIONAL
                         -- If present, version MUST be v3
    }
```

Since you've provided a TBSCertificate, not a Certificate, when it expected to see SEQUENCE, SEQUENCE, but got SEQUENCE, [0], it errored out.

Nothing in ASN.1 DER encoding says "this structure is a TBSCertificate", the structure is just a definition of the order data should be written or read.  So the `openssl x509` command doesn't have any inkling that you've stripped off the outer SEQUENCE (the Certificate structure).  `openssl asn1parse` shows what the data contains.  "I'm a sequence, my content is this long.   I'm a sequence, my content is this long.  I'm a context-specific-0, my content is this long and it is 0x02. ..."

> What should I do if I want to see tbsCertificate in txt to know what exactly are encrypted.

Nothing in the certificate is encrypted.

"TBSCertificate" is "to be signed certificate".  The outer structure is { "all the contents", "how did it get signed", "the signature" }.  The `openssl x509` command on the certificate already showed you what was in the TBSCertificate value... the version number, subject, validity, issuer, etc.

Comment: Nit: while many OpenSSL commands (and related library routines) can read only a single data structure which must be as expected, `x509` (and the `d2i` and `PEM_read` routines for it) is an exception: it can read _either_ a standard cert,. which is exactly the structure you quote, OR a standard cert _followed by_ another, separate ASN.1 DER SEQUENCE containing some OpenSSL-specific metadata. In PEM this is `BEGIN/END TRUSTED CERTIFICATE` instead of standard `CERTIFICATE` and in the C code it is type `X509_AUX`. (Otherwise concur.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Nit nit: d2i_X509_AUX can read both the plain cert and the cert+aux concatenation, but d2i_X509 will only read the standard cert (d2i_X509_AUX calls d2i_X509). Similarly for the PEM routines (because they call the d2i functions). But, yeah, the x509 console command does use the AUX versions, so it's slightly more flexible than I implied.